# AWS Face identification from a group image

Tags: amazon-web-services, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

AWS only allows us to compare the largest one face in a group image against collection, then how should I identify other faces in that image.

I know face recognition is possible in an image with multiple faces, but that only provides bounding boxes of faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [SearchFacesByImage - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html):

> To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the `IndexFaces` operation, and then use the face IDs returned in subsequent calls to the `SearchFaces` operation.

`IndexFaces` detects up to 100 faces in an image and returns Bounding Box information about each face. Therefore, you could:

- Call `IndexFaces` on the source image
- **Loop** through each face returned and:

  - Extract the **Bounding Box** for the face
  - Use a graphics library (eg ImageMagick) to **crop the source image to that bounding box**
  - Pass the cropped image to `SearchFaces`

Comment: Actually I expect this Answer, Also I want to Confirm this is the exact method possible, with this suggestion(ImageMagick). thanks. Is There Any Alternative For AWS Rekognition that also Solves this problem.